# how to check if any of the files in a directory changed

Tags: linux, file, directory, filesystems, stat

Given a directory, I'd like to know whether the files in the directory have been modified or not. (Boolean) i.e. if the directory's state has changed from before.

I don't want to run a file watcher service for this as I don't need to know which file has been modified (or if many files change receive many events)

I've looked at `atime`, `mtime`, `ctime` from `stat`

eg: for a dir named `taskmaster` which already contains `sample.txt`

```
stat taskmaster
```

output

```sh
  File: taskmaster
  Size: 245760      Blocks: 480        IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 1309314     Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-05-22 21:25:06.226421200 +0530
Modify: 2020-05-22 21:25:06.222175900 +0530
Change: 2020-05-22 21:25:06.222175900 +0530
 Birth: -
```

After I modify the folder contents

```sh
# modify an existing file
echo modify > taskmaster/sample.txt
```

`stat taskmaster` gives

```sh
  File: taskmaster
  Size: 245760      Blocks: 480        IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 1309314     Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-05-22 21:25:06.226421200 +0530
Modify: 2020-05-22 21:25:06.222175900 +0530
Change: 2020-05-22 21:25:06.222175900 +0530
 Birth: -
```

The exact same output.

If no file is removed or deleted the access and modify times do not change. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do `stat` on individual files, something like this :

```
previous="$(stat *)"

while sleep 60; do
    current="$(stat *)"
    if  [[ $current != $previous ]]; then
        echo "Some files changed."
    fi
    previous=$current
done
```

Comment: Is this efficient if I have thousands of files in that folder? which unfortunately is my use case (to compress the directory only when something changes because I have many files)

Comment: @PhaniRithvij, `stat *` takes 7 seconds for 10000 files.

Comment: Ok I'll accept this if no better solution comes out.

Comment: If I receive no better answers for some time I'll accept your answer. Because I was intending this to be much efficient.

Comment: `stat -c %Y /path/to/directory`  also works, then just use the timestamp

Comment: @AndyGee What if owner changed but timestamp stayed the same ? Can this happen ?

Comment: @Philippe - hi, basically no, I added an answer below to explain this in more detail. However according to the docs writing bytes to a file should certainly make a change as per the OPs `echo modify > taskmaster/sample.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Earlier comment: `stat -c %Y /path/to/directory` also works, does have a ceveat.
There are several fields that the stat command reads and accesses and it depends on how the contents of the direcctory were modified.

`stat` command output uses `st_mtime`

```
printf("Last file modification:   %s", ctime(&sb.st_mtime));
```

Source: https://www.pdl.cmu.edu/posix/docs/POSIX-stat-manpages.pdf

Stat documentation
The field st_mtime for a file is changed by file modifications, e.g. by mknod(2), truncate(2), utime(2) and write(2) (of more than zero bytes).

`st_mtime` of a directory is changed by the creation or deletion of files in that directory. The `st_mtime` field is not changed for changes in owner, group, hard link count, or mode.

Source: http://man.he.net/man2/stat

So if a file is created, written to or deleted within a directory, the directory modified time will be automatically updated, but not if an additional hardlink or permissions are changed on a file within that directory.

I cannot find information on casading the changes up towards `/` but the directories `utime` cchange 'should' propagate this upwards but possibly not immediately. I would cetainly test that though for your use case.